# Laravel 9 Get Tax Rate for User

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Is there currently a way to get a users tax rate based on their customer profile in Stripe/Cashier? I see in the Stripe API there is a method for tax_rates (https://docs.stripe.com/api/tax_rates/list) but it doesn't appear to be an option in Laravel Cashier. I am able to use Cashier::findBillable() to get the accounts taxIds but they don't show the tax rate. I basically need to get a users tax rate so I can show it during checkout and then again when I send out a one-time invoice to the user. It won't be subscription based billing.

Comment: I ended up using TaxJar for this instead of Stripe Tax. The Stripe Tax SDK would work with Cashier, but have to create a checkout session, add products, add prices, and then tax would auto generate within the checkout session. It was more work than what I needed so used the TaxJar API to get the tax rate for a location.